# BroadcastReceiver is not working after boot complete

Tags: java, c#, android

I am working on an app In this, I have to send the current status of the  android devices in 30-30 seconds through my  app which I have done. But the problem I am facing is the app is not starting after boot complete this problem is related to some of android devices.

MY Code is:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootCompletedReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"action : "+intent.getAction());
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction()).equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Log.d(TAG,"receive boot completes : "+intent.getAction());
            @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
            AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                    super.onPostExecute(o);
                    context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, StatUpdateService.class));
                }
            };

            task.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifests file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
   
<......./>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

List item

On Some of the  android devices, This Code is working and My app is  starting after boot complete, but on the Some of the android devices, it's not working.

Comment: Please check may be machine configuration issue or supported hardware and software is available on your IIP machine. and also check android version on both IIP machine.

Comment: Please stop using AsyncTask in 2022...

Answer (score 1):

Android does not auto-start any application until you manually launch it at least once. After that, the applications will automatically start on each Android boot.

Add `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in your manifest.

When Android finishes booting and is ready to start the home activity, the home event is sent and qualifying applications identify themselves as bootable candidates. The system sends out the `android.intent.category.HOME` and `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` intents when it's done initializing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.test.app">

    <!-- add this -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:theme="@style/app_theme_red">

        <!-- main -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <!-- main filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <!-- add this -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- boot receiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
    
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I added                                                                               
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                <category android:name="a ndroid.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                     
     code on my project but it's not working.

Comment: Running your application manually from launch icon (click at least once on launch icon), then reboot your android phone.

Comment: Dont forget, disable android.intent.category.HOME for show the launch icons.

Comment: Yes, But I want to start my service after boot complete.

Comment: Look at here for details https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001546/task/android/t_faq_autostart_custom_android_applications.htm

Comment: Note Due to security reasons, Android does not auto-start any application until you manually launch it at least once. After that, the applications will automatically start on each Android boot.